# What is the origin of fasting during the holy month of Ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, source-identification

What is the origin of fasting during the holy month of Ramadan?
Is it related to the war of Karbala anyway?

Comment: What made you think there is connection with Karbala?

Comment: I have heard Imam Hasan and Husain fasted during the war. that made me think.

Comment: According to generally accepted histories Imam Hasan was not alive at the time of the war.

Comment: May I ask the reason of downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Origin is Qur'an:

[Surat Al-Baqarah: 2/183](http://quran.com/2/183), [Surat Al-Baqarah: 2/185](http://quran.com/2/185) and [Surat Al-Baqarah: 2/187](http://quran.com/2/185)

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا كُتِبَ عَلَيْكُمُ الصِّيَامُ كَمَا
>   كُتِبَ عَلَى الَّذِينَ مِن قَبْلِكُمْ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَتَّقُونَ ﴿البقرة:
>   ١٨٣﴾
>
> O believers, prescribed for you is the Fast, even as it was
>   prescribed for those that were before you -- happily you will be
>   god fearing -- [Surat Al-Baqarah: 2/183](http://quran.com/2/183)
>
> شَهْرُ رَمَضَانَ الَّذِي أُنزِلَ فِيهِ الْقُرْآنُ هُدًى لِّلنَّاسِ
>   وَبَيِّنَاتٍ مِّنَ الْهُدَىٰ وَالْفُرْقَانِ فَمَن شَهِدَ مِنكُمُ
>   الشَّهْرَ فَلْيَصُمْهُ وَمَن كَانَ مَرِيضًا أَوْ عَلَىٰ سَفَرٍ
>   فَعِدَّةٌ مِّنْ أَيَّامٍ أُخَرَ يُرِيدُ اللَّهُ بِكُمُ الْيُسْرَ وَلَا
>   يُرِيدُ بِكُمُ الْعُسْرَ وَلِتُكْمِلُوا الْعِدَّةَ وَلِتُكَبِّرُوا
>   اللَّهَ عَلَىٰ مَا هَدَاكُمْ وَلَعَلَّكُمْ تَشْكُرُونَ ﴿البقرة: ١٨٥﴾
>
> the month of Ramadan, wherein the Qu'ran was sent down to be a guidance
>   to the people, and as clear signs of the Guidance and the Salvation.
>   So let those of you, who are present at the month, fast it; and if any
>   of you be sick, or if he be on a journey, then a number of other days;
>   Allah desires ease for you, and desires not hardship for you; and that
>   you fulfill the number, and magnify Allah that He has guided you, and
>   happily you will be thank. [Surat Al-Baqarah: 2/185](http://quran.com/2/185)
>
> أُحِلَّ لَكُمْ لَيْلَةَ الصِّيَامِ الرَّفَثُ إِلَىٰ نِسَائِكُمْ هُنَّ
>   لِبَاسٌ لَّكُمْ وَأَنتُمْ لِبَاسٌ لَّهُنَّ عَلِمَ اللَّهُ أَنَّكُمْ
>   كُنتُمْ تَخْتَانُونَ أَنفُسَكُمْ فَتَابَ عَلَيْكُمْ وَعَفَا عَنكُمْ
>   فَالْآنَ بَاشِرُوهُنَّ وَابْتَغُوا مَا كَتَبَ اللَّهُ لَكُمْ وَكُلُوا
>   وَاشْرَبُوا حَتَّىٰ يَتَبَيَّنَ لَكُمُ الْخَيْطُ الْأَبْيَضُ مِنَ
>   الْخَيْطِ الْأَسْوَدِ مِنَ الْفَجْرِ ثُمَّ أَتِمُّوا الصِّيَامَ إِلَى
>   اللَّيْلِ وَلَا تُبَاشِرُوهُنَّ وَأَنتُمْ عَاكِفُونَ فِي الْمَسَاجِدِ
>   تِلْكَ حُدُودُ اللَّهِ فَلَا تَقْرَبُوهَا كَذَٰلِكَ يُبَيِّنُ اللَّهُ
>   آيَاتِهِ لِلنَّاسِ لَعَلَّهُمْ يَتَّقُونَ ﴿البقرة: ١٨٧﴾
>
> Permitted to you, upon the night of the Fast, is to go in to your
>   wives; -- they are a vestment for you, and you are a vestment for
>   them. Allah knows that you have been betraying yourselves, and has
>   turned to you and pardoned you. So now lie with them, and seek what
>   Allah has prescribed for you. And eat and drink, until the white
>   thread shows clearly to you from the black thread at the dawn; then
>   complete the Fast unto the night, and do not lie with them while you
>   cleave to the mosques. Those are Allah's bounds; keep well within
>   them. So Allah makes clear His signs to men; happily they will be
>   Allah fearing. [Surat Al-Baqarah: 2/187](http://quran.com/2/185)

Comment: Thank you for wonderfully describing it through citations. One more question.. If I have to travel for 2 days during Ramzan. I am free to not to fast. Right? Can I fast for 2 days after Eid-ul-Fitr to compensate it. Or those 2 days can't be compensated?

Comment: You are welcome. According to [Al-Bagharah: 2/185](http://quran.com/2/185): ...وَمَن كَانَ مَرِيضًا أَوْ عَلَىٰ سَفَرٍ فَعِدَّةٌ مِّنْ أَيَّامٍ أُخَرَ يُرِيدُ اللَّهُ بِكُمُ الْيُسْرَ وَلَا يُرِيدُ بِكُمُ الْعُسْرَ... (...and if any of you be sick, or if he be on a journey, then [compensate] a number of other days; Allah desires ease for you, and desires not hardship for you...) So you are allowed to travel and then compensate it after Ramadan. "Allah desires ease for you"

Comment: @Inshan it is more complicated than that verse